# Fastest way to capitalize words

Tags: c++, boost, stdstring

What is the fastest way to capitalize words (std::string) using C++?

On Debian Linux using g++ 4.6.3 with the -O3 flag, this function using `boost::to_lower` will capitalize 81,450,625 words in roughly 24 seconds in a single thread of execution on a AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1090T Processor (3200 MHz).

```
void Capitalize( std::string& word )
{
    boost::to_lower( word );
    word[0] = toupper( word[0] );
}
```

This function using `std::transform` does the same thing in roughly 10 seconds. I clear the VM between testing, so I don't think this difference is a fluke:

`sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

```
void Capitalize( std::string& word )
{
    std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
    word[0] = toupper( word[0] );
}
```

Are there faster ways? I would not want to lose portability for the sake of speed, but if there are faster ways to do this that work in std C++ or std C++ with boost, I'd like to try them.

Thanks.

Comment: Is capitilizing really a bottleneck?

Comment: To optimize, you have to profile the code to determine the bottleneck.  Once you know what the bottleneck is, you may be able to devise a faster solution.  Also, have you compared the results of the two solutions so that you know if they actually do the same thing?  Perhaps boost works with UTF-8 or provides better locale and Unicode support (or vice versa).

Comment: As a minor optimization with the std::transform one, you could start at word.begin() + 1, so that you don't call `tolower` on the first character which you are going to send to `toupper`.

Comment: Where is the data coming from?  If you're reading from disk, it's likely that IO will be your bottleneck.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Yes, the words are coming from a file on disk. I realize that IO will likely be the slow part at some point. I don't think I've hit that yet.

Answer (score 7):

Had this exact question when dealing with DNA sequences where the input is not guaranteed to be upper case, and where `boost::to_upper` was a bottle-neck in the code. Changing to this:

```
template<typename T_it>
void SequenceToUpperCase( T_it begin, T_it end )
{
    // Convert to upper: clear the '32' bit, 0x20 in hex. And with the
    // inverted bit string (~).
    for ( auto it = begin; it != end; ++it )
        *it &= ~0x20;
}
```

resulted in a huge speed increase. I'm sure it is possible to further optimize by e.g. flipping 8 bytes at once but with the above code the upper-case is near-instantaneous for us. For lower-case: do:

```
        *it |= 0x20;
```

Answer (score 5):

Few ways to make it faster:
1. Don't use `to_lower`, it's slow. Don't use `if`s either, Make a table with 256 entries that maps from character to its lowercase version and another table for uppercase.
2. Don't use `transform`, take a pointer to the first character and loop until the null terminator.
3. If memory is not a problem, use a table that maps 2 character sequences. In this case you will need another table that handles termination.
4. If you can do this in assembly, it will be much faster.

Comment: Don't think it is only Latin alphabet in the world!

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support any of these?  `std::transform` will typically be completely inlined, for instance.

Comment: `to_lower` is non-standard. OTOH, `tolower` is often implemented using a lookup table (one of the reasons why you are encouraged to pass an `unsigned int` rather than a signed `int`).

Answer (score 2):

If capitalizing is a **really** bottleneck then write your own implementation of capitalization with hand-written cycle and inline toupper/tolower functions. 
Use ASM if it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I have an implementation I found it faster than std::transform , Compiled in g++ -03 Fedora 18.

```
performance time in seconds :
transform took         : 11 s
my implementation took : 2 s
Test data size = 26*15*9999999 chars
```

```
inline void tolowerPtr(char *p) ;

inline void tolowerStr(std::string& s)
{char* c=const_cast<char*>(s.c_str());
size_t l = s.size();
  for(char* c2=c;c2<c+l;c2++)tolowerPtr(c2); 
};

inline void tolowerPtr(char *p) 
{
switch(*p)
{
  case 'A':*p='a'; return;
  case 'B':*p='b'; return;
  case 'C':*p='c'; return;
  case 'D':*p='d'; return;
  case 'E':*p='e'; return;
  case 'F':*p='f'; return;
  case 'G':*p='g'; return;
  case 'H':*p='h'; return;
  case 'I':*p='i'; return;
  case 'J':*p='j'; return;
  case 'K':*p='k'; return;
  case 'L':*p='l'; return;
  case 'M':*p='m'; return;
  case 'N':*p='n'; return;
  case 'O':*p='o'; return;
  case 'P':*p='p'; return;
  case 'Q':*p='q'; return;
  case 'R':*p='r'; return;
  case 'S':*p='s'; return;
  case 'T':*p='t'; return;
  case 'U':*p='u'; return;
  case 'V':*p='v'; return;
  case 'W':*p='w'; return;
  case 'X':*p='x'; return;
  case 'Y':*p='y'; return;
  case 'Z':*p='z'; return;
};
return ;
}

void testtransform( std::string& word )
{
std::string word2=word; 
time_t t;
time_t t2;
time(&t);
std::cout << "testtransform: start " << "\n";
int i=0;
for(;i<9999999;i++) 
{    word2=word;
    std::transform(word2.begin(), word2.end(), word2.begin(), ::tolower);
}
time(&t2);
std::cout << word2 << "\n";
std::cout << "testtransform: end " << i << ":"<< t2-t << "\n";
}

void testmytolower( std::string& word )
{
std::string word2=word; 
time_t t;
time_t t2;
time(&t);
std::cout << "testmytolower: start " << "\n";
int i=0;
for(;i<9999999;i++)
{   word2=word;
    cstralgo::tolowerStr(word2);
}
time(&t2);
std::cout << word2 << "\n";
std::cout << "testmytolower: end " << i << ":"<< t2-t << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::string word ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   word =word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word;
   testtransform( word);
   testmytolower( word);
   return 0;
}
```

I will be glad to know if performance can be improved further.

Comment: Similarly you can implement toUpper

Answer (score 0):

I would use a for loop to go through the entire string, character by character, parsing them to a function to convert to uppercase. To hopefully speed things up, I'll write the capitalisation function in assembly. The C++ component of the application would be like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

extern "C" char asm_capt(char x);

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    string tmp = str;

    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){

        tmp.at(i) = asm_capt(str.at(i));
    }

}
```

Now comes the assembly part; I'll assume you are using Windows and the MASM compiler. The code should be saved within a .asm source file, and included in the project with MASM build settings:

```
.model flat
.code
_asm_capt proc

    mov rax, rcx
    cmp rax, 61h
    jl already_capt

    sub rax, 20h
    ret

    already_capt:

    ret

_asm_capt endp
end
```

Essentially, it checks if the character (in hexadecimal) is less than 0x61, which would imply, if you only use letters, that it is already capitalised. otherwise, the value is decreased by 0x20, which moves it to the lower case equivalent. (See ASCII table.)

---

**Note:** By default, the return parameter is stored in the RAX register; the first parameter passed by C++ to assembly is stored in RCX.

Answer (score -1):

Required pseudocode would be:

for(int i=0 to given_str.length)
{ upper[i]=(char*)given_str[i]-32;  // in ascii tbl, any lower case char - upper case char=32
}
return upper;